# It's a good security scheme save user data in different MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I'm programming a sensitive application (health data) that requires a good security schema. Of course, bugs exists and hackers or user may found it. So my concern is to protect data as much as I can. Reading something about security I have found a mechanism that could be useful, but I would like to listen the opinion of someone more experienced in this stuff. The scheme is:

- Create a database, call it 'app' for example
- Create some common tables (or not)
- For each user, create a set of tables with a prefix based on the user name and a hash to avoid a user to known other user prefix (sjiXoi4sa_table)
- All database queries for a user will put his own prefix except those refered to the global scope

Is this a good security scheme? Could it be improved? (for instance, it will be great if each user may encrypt their own tables). Any suggestion welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you describe it, the schema does nothing to improve security - OTOH, the additional overhead in working with more tables means more code means more defects injected. You are also compromising performance with this approach.

However if you were to set up the permissions so that a user only had read/write access to their own tables, then yes, it would be more secure - however you've still caused yourself a lot of problems elsewhere. You can get the same level of security AND reduce the complexity / amount of code AND solve the performance / scalability problems by normalising the data properly, and denying all access by users to the tables - but grant access via stored procedures (where you can effectively apply permissions on a row-by-row basis).

Comment: Sounds interesting. Please, could you show some code or provide any link to understand better this (stored-procedures)

Answer (score 2):

This is security by obscurity, and doesn't add any protection. If the site is hacked, the hacker will just dump the mysql database, not just the user table

Comment: Really I'm not concered about a good hacker that could get access to the site. It this happens, you are lost :) I'm concerned about some "power-users" or "casual-hackers" that might found a bug in the code like a function that forgets to check if the user has permission to read that record in a table.

Comment: If a function forgets to check if a user has permission to read a certain piece of data, it wont help having the data on another database. The site will still show them the data as it would not have any obstruction to pulling the data from the second database. If a function doesn't check a users privileges it will function in the same way regardless of the users right to view that data.

Comment: I totally agree: security by obscurity is not a solution... it may make things a bit more difficult for certains (not attackers) users, but is not the solution

Answer (score 1):

This will do nothing to address the security issues in your application and will have the added disadvantage of impacting on performance (creation of tables, indices etc). Consider encrypting data instead and locking down access to user specific data based on which user is logged into your system.

Comment: Encrypt data will be a great solution, but how? Do you have any link or code snippet to show how to encrypt parts of table data according to user access?

Comment: Well you could encrypt the data, say using the blowfish algorithm, with something based on the users id or access level as part of the salt.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to everyone else's answer to why your schema is a bad idea, here's another piece of advice: Your dealing with health data, so there are probably regulations that you must follow to ensure security. For example, [NIST standards](http://www.nist.gov/index.html) or whatever your national equivalent is. Find them, read them, follow them. In many jurisdictions around the world such standards are mandatory, and you could be liable for damages if something happens and you didn't follow the standards.

So, find out what (if any) standards apply to processing and storing private health data in your country, and use them.

Comment: Yeah, of course, the app follows the standars, but I'm looking for an extra security layer. Any case, it's a good advice :)

Comment: The standards should also dictate minimum encryption standards, who can have access to the data, backup procedures, splitting app data and client data over different databases, etcetera. Just follow them all. Security is **hard**. Don't try to invent new security schemes yourself. Anyone can invent a security system they themselves cannot break. The trick is coming up with schemas nobody can break :-)

Comment: Well, in my country (Spain), security standards for this kind of app only talks about the use of HTTPS, no deeper security measures are mandatory (of course daily backups and similar are mandatory, but it doesn't protect against a programmer mistake)

Answer (score 0):

Any scheme that requires the creation of a new set of tables for every new record in another table is too horrible to use except in obfuscation contests, no matter how much security it adds. And as already pointed out, it doesn't add much security either.

Comment: I agree, I don't want to do this, but I have to prevent some users to access other users tables if there is a bug in the application